# Dynamic sky not showing up in Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

After creating a sky from the in-built addon 'Dynamic Sky', the sky shows in the cycles viewport. But disappears when I render the image.
Using the Cyles Render with Cuda GPU compute.
The images are below for reference. [image: In Viewport]

[image: After Render]

Comment: Maybe check the depth of field or volumetrics? There is something in your file that is blurring stuff far away, like the edge of the land plane.

Comment: @susu How do I reduce the brightness?

Comment: @susu The strength in world properties has no effect in bringing the sky back in the render. Reducing it is only affecting the brightness caused by the sky at the mountain and the water.

Comment: @susu  Thanks for the help. The issue resolved. There was a plane which I hid at the start of the project right behind the scenery and in front of the sky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved. There was a plane which I hid at the start of the project right behind the scenery and in front of the sky.

Answer (score -1):

Go to  *Edit > Preferences > Addons* . Using search field find *Dynamic Sky*

Check the box and close the window you will get the button to create the dynamic sky